# Show tree structure in Azure Monitor Workbook

Tags: azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

If I navigate to the "Logs"-section in Azure to find the entries of my Azure Monitor, I get a tree structure that looks like this:

[image]

In this example I am just showing all exceptions without any formatting.
By default I can expand an entry and then expand the stack trace etc.

I want to get the same behaviour inside of a workbook.
But here my items do not have any tree like structure. I just get a list of items like this:

[image]

The only thing I found was to change the column settings like this:

[image]

But this is not doing what I want. I think my exceptions do not have an id-parent id structure.
Any proposals how I can just show the same result in the workbook like in the normal query editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid control used by workbooks doesn't currently have that "Expand" behavior that the logs view does for expanding a single row inline.

The closest thing you can do, in the column settings for the grid, you can set a column to be a link, and have that link either:

- open up the "cell details" view to get a side panel with the contents of that specific cell (useful if the cell contains json or other content)
- open up the "generic details" view that shows all of the contents in that row

so for example in this example making the "tablename" column a text renderer (you can use links with any kind of renderer though), and making it open up the "generic details" view with these settings:
[image: column settings turning on link]

will result in a popup on the side that looks like:
[image: generic details view]

(in this case i only have 2 columns so it isn't very exciting!)

Comment: Super! Thats very helpful already :)